# Best way to remove all associations has_and_belongs_to_many without deleting the records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a `user` model that `has_and_belongs_to_many :clubs` so I can seen e.g. `clubs.users` and it returns all the users for that club. What I want to do is remove/break the associations all the users for that club. I want the users to still exist but just not be associated to that club anymore.

I am aware of e.g. `club.users.delete_all` but that ended up deleting the users as well. I cannot think of another way to approach this for removing all of the records.

Worth noting I know you can do `club.users.delete(user)` I am unsure how to pass in all the users associated to that club to that method. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the clubs users to an empty array will destroy the relationship without harming either entity!

Comment: though issue comes if they belong to more than one club. I dont want to wipe all of their clubs. Its more from a clubs perspective so I could try clubs.users = []